# How to make a MS Ofiice type dropdown button in tabbar on top left corner in wxribbon in wxpython

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, ribbon

I am building a GUI with wxribbon in wxpython and I have everything working great. Now, I want to have a 'Orb' like button on top left corner, near the first tab which will be like a File button with dropdown menu but I am not able to find any support for that in wxwidget or wxpython. It would be really great if anyone could help me on how to do that. Thanks.... I was thinking of something like using brute force approach and creating a button with absolute position but I don't know it will work or not. Anyone having any idea please help me...

Comment: I don't know if it will work to brute force place the button as you say, but I can't think of any other way.  Why don't you try it :)

Comment: Are you using wxWidgets 3.0?

Comment: No, I am using wxwidget 2.8. Is making that possible in wxwidget 3.0